# angularjs scope not loaded after loading template as a popup dialog

Tags: angularjs

On a button click I want to open a modal dialog window and load template (`.html`) page into the popup window. Inside my template I have drop-down list which needs to be binded with data from database (in my case receiving data from Angularjs Factory service WCF Service call)

Dropdown is not loading after dialog window open.

Find my code below: My first controller to open a popup dialog:

```
app.controller('MyFirstController', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.showTrackingPopup = function () {
        var Id = 111;        
        var popupTpl = document.createElement("div");
        popupTpl.setAttribute("id", "TestDialog");
        popupTpl.setAttribute("ng-app", "MyApp");
        popupTpl.setAttribute("ng-include", "'app/templates/Test-template.html'");
        popupTpl.setAttribute("ng-controller", "MySecondController");
        popupTpl.setAttribute("ng-init", "InitData(Id)");
        var popupScope = $scope.$new();
        popupScope.someValue = Math.random();
        var popupLinker = $compile(popupTpl);
        var popupElement = popupLinker(popupScope);

        var dialog = $('<div/>').html(popupElement);

        dialog.dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: { my: "left", at: "center", of: window },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $('body').find('#TestDialog ').remove();
                popupScope.$destroy();
            }
        });      
        return false;
      }
});
```

My Second Controller which get data from database and loaded into scope to ng-repeat and bind dropdown control:

```
app.controller(' MySecondController ', function ($scope, $compile, $http, $rootScope,    FactService) {
    $scope.DropDownData = [];

    $scope.InitData = function (Id) {
        $scope.DropDownData = FactService.GetDropdownData(Id);        
    }
});
```

How to wait the second controller till data returns from Factory service and then drop down gets loaded automatically?  Please help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be very sure without knowing what `FactService.GetDropdownData` returns but under normal circumstances, it should be a $http promise. In that case, you have to load your dropdown data when this promise is fulfilled.

For example:

```
FactService.GetDropdownData(Id).
.success(function(data){
    // your $http promise was fullfiled successfuly and you have your data
    $scope.DropDownData = data;
}
.error(function(err){ /* handler your error here */});
```

Also, I am not very sure that Id value is getting passed properly in ng-init the way you do it. It's also considered a bad practice manipulating the DOM in your controllers, consider creating a directive instead. In case you want easier popups out of the box, you might want to consider the [Angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) module

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.  Angular-ui bootstrap css are messing up my website.  From above controllers how to add scope dropdowndata in first controller and add watcher to the ng repeat in template.  And in second controller apply digest to update view? I am facing binding issue here. Is that approach correct?